# First try in TeX problem

Tags: miktex

I have just installed MikTeX and WinEdt and i try this code in WinEdt:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[electronic]{ifsym}
\usepackage[cp1251]{inputenc}
\usepackage[matrix,arrow,curve,frame,poly,arc]{xy}
\usepackage[english, russian]{babel}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\sum x

\end{document}`
```

Then i press on TeX button (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and it says a lot of errors of the same type: "Undefined Control Sequence".

Then i press on DVI button and see something like this:

> article amsmath amsfonts,amssymb amsthm [electronic]ifsym
>   [cp1251]inputenc     [matrix,arrow,curve,frame,poly,arc]xy [english,
>   russian]babel [¯nal]graphicx mathrsfs color tikz empty document
>
> x

What should i do? Whats the problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I don't know WinEdt, but I suspect you're compiling with `pdftex` instead of `pdflatex`. The only error you should get from that code is `missing $ inserted`, because `\sum` must be in math mode, i.e. `\[ \sum x \]` or `$ \sum x $`.

Comment: Or in addition to  Torbjørn's solution: `\( \sum x \)` or `\begin{math} \sum x \end{math}` work too.

Comment: As a follow up to @ChristianH.'s comment: If you use `\( .. \)` then you should also add `\usepackage{fixltx2e}` (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/542/586), and the `math` environment is basically the same as `$ .. $` I believe.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. What does `fixltx2e` fix actually? I never heard of that before?

Comment: This and that, see the documentation. In this specific case it protects `\( .. \)` so they can be used in moving arguments, e.g. section titles and captions. Try for example `\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
\chapter{\( x \)}
\newpage abc
\end{document}` which doesn't work with `fixltx2e`.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Good to know, but I recently switched over to use `\( ... \)` and try to prevent chapter (etc) titles with mathematical markup, but your proposition does even allow for using this style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is simply that you try to compile with `Plain TeX` and you wrote a `LaTeX`document, that can be compiled with `LaTeX` (Shift+Ctrl+L) or `pdfLaTeX` (no shortcut,  but you have an icon in the toolbar that lets you choose the compiler:

[image]

You also can use LaTeXify or pdfLaTeXify to automatically compile the right number of times if your document has cross-references, bibliography, index &c.

Btw, you should use `usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` rather than cp1251: WinEdt is an utf8 editor, and it will make your document easily readable on any platform.

Comment: I tried LaTeX compiling, but it says that it failed to create a dvi file :( It says "for possible explanations start the command from the command prompt", but i don't know which command...

Comment: This seems to be a miktex/latex problem. What does the .log file say?

Comment: I forgot to answer your question: "starting  from the command prompt" in its simplest form just means typing at the command prompt: `latex file_name.tex`. It will compile in LaTeX format, and you will see the .log file. But anyway you also see it in WinEdt console.

Comment: Ok, i have installed the newest version of MiKTeX and it seems to work now)